# How to pass a variable which is outside my template literal?

Tags: javascript

I am putting my parsed JSON in a variable, and now I want to pass it in a template literal.

I am putting the parsed json in the variable 'discoverdata',

```
discover.open('GET', 'https://api.deezer.com/chart');
// tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
discover.onload = function() {
  var discoverdata = JSON.parse(discover.responseText);
  console.log(discoverdata.tracks.data);
};
discover.send();
```

and I want to call this variable in my template literal over here,

```
document.getElementById('discover').innerHTML = `
${I want the variable to go in here}
`;
```

Thanks in advance :**{**)

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById('discover').innerHTML = `
${discoverdata.tracks.data}
`;
```

Comment: when I do that it says it cannot find the name 'discoverdata'

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You should consider adding more information about your answer.